# Qt5 detecting widgets under an other one

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to detect if two widgets are overlapping without any success. Here is a minimal example:

### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void hover();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "hover.h"
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QPushButton* pb = new QPushButton("Button", this);
    setCentralWidget(pb);
    connect(pb, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(hover()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}

void MainWindow::hover()
{
    Hover* h = new Hover(centralWidget());
    h->show();
}
```

### hover.h

```
#ifndef HOVER_H
#define HOVER_H

#include <QDialog>

class QMoveEvent;

class Hover : public QDialog
{
public:
    Hover(QWidget* w, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());

protected:
    void moveEvent(QMoveEvent* event);

private:
    QWidget* w;
};

#endif // HOVER_H
```

### hover.cpp

```
Hover::Hover(QWidget* w, Qt::WindowFlags f) : QDialog(nullptr, f), w(w)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
}

void Hover::moveEvent(QMoveEvent* event)
{
    if(qApp->widgetAt(event->pos()) == w)
    {
        qDebug() << "YES"; // Never triggered.
    }
}
```

As you can see above, I re implemented the `QDialog::moveEvent` of the `Hover` class in order to get notified when the widgets is dragged onto the `MainWindow`'s `QPushButton`. However, when I move the dialog over the button, it does not work.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks for your answers.

### Edit

I played around with eyllanesc's code. It works well for the above sample. However I noticed something weird when using `QPropertyAnimation`. In fact, the global coordinates of the `QPushButton` seem to be wrong. The `x` coordinate of the `QPushButton` is slightly offset to the right.
Just replace the code of the `MainWindow` by the following one:

### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
class QPushButton;
class Hover;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void hover();

private:
    QPushButton* pb;
    Hover* h;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "hover.h"
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    pb = new QPushButton("Button", this);
    connect(pb, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(hover()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}

void MainWindow::hover()
{
    QPropertyAnimation* a = new QPropertyAnimation(pb, "geometry");
    a->setDuration(1000);
    a->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, pb->width(), pb->height()));
    a->setEndValue(QRect(50, 50, pb->width(), pb->height()));
    a->start();
    h = new Hover(pb);
    h->setGeometry(300, 300, 50, 100);
    h->show();
}
```

Does that happen to you as well? If so, does anyone have an explanation?

Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: Excuse me, but I do not observe that mistake, you could create a test where I can easily observe it.

Comment: @eyllanesc you can download the test by using the following link http://wikisend.com/download/290560/untitled.tar.gz. It is also happening when I move the QPushButton  by using either QWidget::move or QWidget::setGeometry. Everything seems to be fine while the QPushButton is not moved.

Comment: Already update my solution, difference between widgets and windows, are 2 different things, some widgets are windows.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you, everything work as expected.

Comment: Keep doing test and if you have any problem label me, if you had it in github would be great :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the [`widgetAt()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#widgetAt) function we can use the intersection of its areas (according to docs `widgetAt()` is slow)

For this we use the global position through the function [`mapToGlobal()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal) and [`pos()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#pos-prop), and the function `size()`, after that we check if there is an intersection

```
void Hover::moveEvent(QMoveEvent*)
{
    if(!visibleRegion().isNull() && w)
    {
       QRect RectW(w->mapToGlobal(QPoint(QPoint(0,0))), w->size()) ;
       QRect RectHover = QRect(pos(), size());
       if(!RectW.intersected(RectHover).isEmpty())
           qDebug()<<"yes";
       else {
           qDebug()<<"no";
       }
    }
}
```